# Label start of a sequence with NA's

Tags: r

This is trivial question, however I don't seem to find neat solution for this. (without excluding NA's first and including them back again). So I'm looking for some ideas without the need of NA's exclusion.

I would like to label the start of a `0 and 1` sequence with `2` and `1` respectively and replace NA's with 0 as well as the remaining sequence of 0's and 1's.

Is the `rle` function useful here? Base R solution would be welcomed.

Example:

```
x <- c(rep(NA,10),rep(1,5),rep(NA,5),rep(1,10),rep(NA,3),rep(0,7),rep(NA,15),rep(1,9))
r <- c(0,diff(x)); r[r %in% -1] <- 2
```

From this sample data:

```
x
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Desired output:

`[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `rle` to create a grouping variable ('gr') to `split` the 'x' into a `list`.  Replace the first element that is 0 or 1 with 2 or 1 using `match`, concatenate with 0s, `unlist` and then replace the NA elements with 0.

```
xN <- x
xN[is.na(xN)] <- -999
v1 <- rle(xN)$lengths
gr <- rep(seq_along(v1), v1)


x1 <- unlist(lapply(split(x, gr), function(x) 
          c(match(x[1],1:0),rep(0,length(x)-1)) ), use.names=FALSE)
x1[is.na(x1)] <- 0
x1
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
#[39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Or instead of `split`, we can use `which` and `diff` to replace the values.

```
x1 <- (!x)+2*(!is.na(x))-1
ind <- which(!is.na(x))
x1[c(ind[c(FALSE,diff(ind)==1)], which(is.na(x)))] <- 0
x1
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
#[39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

Or we can use `rleid` from the devel version of `data.table` as grouping variable.  Replace the first element of 0's and 1's with 2 and 1 using `match` and change the NA values to 0.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
DT <- setDT(list(x))
DT[, c(match(V1[1], 1:0), rep(0, .N-1)) ,rleid(V1)][is.na(V1), V1:=0]$V1
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
#[39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: would be there a base R solution? (just asking). Thanks.

Comment: @Maximilian We can use `rle`.

Comment: `rle` solution would be great! :) Any base R solution would do of course.

Comment: @Maximilian  Updated with an `rle` option

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wish I could up vote more than once. However I will do so on your other answers related to other questions! :)

Comment: @Maximilian  Thanks for your generous comment.  Glad to help you.